# Why do Ray Barone's parents come in the back door half the time?

Tags: everybody-loves-raymond

In the sitcom "Everybody Loves Raymond", Ray Barone's parents live across the street from them which means when they come to visit, it would make sense for them to come in the front door. This is only true half the time however. The other half the time they come in through the backdoor. Why is this? Are they literally walking around to the back of the house to come in?

Comment: Purely speculative, but it's often because people leave their front door locked and their back door open. It's considered unlikely people are going to come round the back to try the door.

Comment: I would chalk it up to creative license.  Half of the scenes take place in the living room, and half take place in the kitchen.  It wouldn't make sense for them to enter from a different room.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger I think that is probably the out of universe reason, however I think its still a little weak. Is it really that hard to have characters enter from another room instead of a door from outside? No. But I can see why a director might want to have them entering through a door to show that they are actually entering the house and weren't inside already all along. I'd be interested in a detailed answer about the stage direction reasons behind this. I've never been involved in television production.

Comment: My neighbors come in both sides of my house without knocking all the time (and they're welcome to), as I don't have a locked fence or doors - were the parents living nearby, do you recall?

Comment: @Mikey yes, they live directly across the street

Comment: They could enter from a different room, but think about the dynamic.  Do we hear the door close and a greeting?  Otherwise it requires another camera cut.  I don't have television production experience either, but this seems the most reasonable explanation.